# SWF in wordpress post

Tags: plugins, posts, security, embed

My question is somewhat a two part question.

First I embedded a SWF file into my blog post using Easy Flash Embed plugin. It shows up on my desktop computer but when I view the post on my mobile device, I can not see the SWF content. Does the plugin Easy FancyBox solve this problem?

My follow-up question is, I'm wondering if embedded SWF files is safe for my blog/website. Should I not use SWFs?

Comment: What mobile device did you test it on? Apple's devices don't have Flash.

Comment: an android device running the latest 4.4 Kitkat

Comment: It sounds as though the issues is your device/plugins, but no, I don't trust Flash to be available on all platforms.

Comment: Try to convert it to HTML5 using for example [Swiffy](https://www.google.com/doubleclick/studio/swiffy/)

Comment: I just made a comment about that :D Thank you. I'll give it a try. This also helps bat away any security concerns I would assume?